# Unable to download WhatsApp

Tags: applications, ios, iphone

I have been trying without success to re-download WhatsApp and every time it says "unable to download". I am not sure if it's a space issue, I would think it would tell me I do not have enough available storage. I am using an iPhone 5c with iOS 10.2.1.

Comment: Are you able to download other apps or upgrade existing apps or is it just WhatsApp?

Comment: I just tried to update another app and that is not working either

Comment: Try to hard reboot your phone, hold the power and home button for about 10 seconds, or until you see the apple logo. Then try again.

Comment: I have tried to restart it and it did not change anything.I think it may be a storage issue. Maybe if I free up some space it might work?

Comment: Go to `Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage`.  You'll see how much free space you have left.

Comment: Try log out of the app store, then doing the reboot mentioned above, then re-login and try to update the app.

Comment: yes I think that I needed to delete some unused stuff. after I opened up some stuff, everything started working fine! thanks all lol :)

Comment: Glad its working.

Answer (score 1):

1) **If the download has started and then the alert pops up**: I have experienced this due to lack of network connections. Sometimes you're connected to WiFi, but there is actually no connection (for example you're connecting to a public WiFi and confirmation is needed).

Go to Safari, type in Google.com and see if Google loads in the browser. If not, find a reliable network connection and try downloading again.

2) **If the alert pops up at the AppStore after you hit the `GET` button, and the download cannot even be started**: your iPhone might not have sufficient space. Go to Settings and check your storage. Delete the Apps, Photos and Podcasts you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

User needed to delete some unused data from the phone to allow the App Store to download the new app updates.